# Why do I get this error when trying to upload an image?

Tags: php, url, uploading

When I go to myserver index and upload and image from there using the interface, it works fine. But as soon as I try to enter the path myself, like:

```
http://myserver/upload.php?image['name']=F:\Bilder\6.jpg
```

it gives me an error that all fields are required. But I have to upload images like this, because I plan to implement it in an app that I'm making. Thing is, that I'm not that well acquainted with php.

here is the upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require("includes/conn.php");


function is_valid_type($file)
{

$valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");

if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
    return 1;
return 0;
}

function showContents($array)
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
}

$TARGET_PATH = "images/";

$image = $_FILES['image'];

$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

if ( $image['name'] == "" )
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

if (!is_valid_type($image))
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{
$sql = "insert into Avatar (filename) values ('" . $image['name'] . "')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " .     mysql_error());

exit;
}
else
{
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}
```

?>

and the index.php

```
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['error']))
                {
                    echo "<span id=\"error\"><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";
                    unset($_SESSION['error']);
                }
                ?>
                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>

                    <label>Avatar</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
                </p>
```

Comment: `http://myserver/upload.php?image['name']=F:\Bilder\6.jpg` is _not_ a valid PHP-expression. What and where, exactly, do you enter this line?

Comment: Well in my browser in order to try to give him an image without using the interface from the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies in

```
if ( $image['name'] == "" )
```

$image has no value there.

You are doing a get request so if you would like to know what the image variable is you should use

```
$_GET['image']
```

Another thing is that you are doing $image = $_FILES['image'];

$_FILES will only be available from a post request.
Uploading files can not be done in the way you are doing now by a parameter from a GET request.

Comment: Thanks, but now he is giving me the next error "Not a valid image" when I try to upload one.

Comment: Simple because you aren't uploading a file. Uploading files can not be done in a GET request. Question is: why can't you use a form to upload your file(s) ?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you refer me to a good documentation (if you know one) or something similar in order to understand better what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

That simply wont work since you cannot upload an image by sending `$_GET[]` variables through the url.

As you can see in the upload.php page you got, the file is retrieved in the php page through a `$_FILES['image']`.

If you change that to `$_GET['image']` and retry to post the link with the get variable you suggest, you probably will be able to see the path to your file but it will only be as a string type and not an actual uploaded file object.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to POST stuff to a web form (as opposed to GETting, which is what you're doing here), you can't just specify the data to be POSTed as part of the URL.

Have a look at those HTTP methods (GET and POST) to understand the difference.

In your app, what you need to do is POST stuff to the URL. Depending on which tools you use to program, you should look into how to send data via POST.

Also, try to see if an implementation of curl (or libcurl) is available to your development platform.